# Is there any way to store element and its frequency together in same data structure?

Tags: c++

I have been working on a problem with arrays and the count of each elements must be considered and changed dynamically then and there. I want to know if there is a way to store both the element and frequency in a single data structure.
*Any solution with code in cpp would be helpful*.

Comment: This sounds like you might want a `std::map<MyElement, int>`

Comment: Your question is too unclear. `struct Data { int elem; int freq } Data myData[100];`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
int main()
{
    int a[]={1,1,1,2,2,3,4};
    map<int,int> m;
    map<int,int>::iterator it;
    for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
    {
        it=m.find(a[i]);
        if(it!=m.end()) it->second++;
        else m.insert(pair<int,int>(a[i],1));
    }
    
    //printing the output
    for(auto i=m.begin();i!=m.end();i++)
    cout<<i->first<<"->"<<i->second<<"\n";
}
```

yeah, you use maps to store the element with its count. Here I have used an iterator along with find function in order to check if the element is present.
if present increase the count by 1 i.e it->second++. else you can insert the new element in the map using insert function.